# Chance of 1 of 3 has a property if chance for the property is given? (How to calc in R?)

Tags: r, statistics, binomial-coefficients

I found this quote in a paper:

> In individuals of Northern European ancestry, as many as 8 percent of men and 0.5 percent of women experience the common form of red-green color blindness. If a submitted manuscript happens to go to three male reviewers of Northern European descent, the chance that at least one will be color blind is 22 percent.

*Wong, B.: Points of view: Color blindness, Nat Methods, 8(6), 441–441, doi:10.1038/nmeth.1618, 2011.*

How could I calculate this in R? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to do it empirically, instead of the analytical way of Joe's answer:

```
n = 100000 #Arbitrary large number
at.least.1 = numeric() #Empty vector to store "1" when at least one was colorblind, "0" if not
for(j in 1:n){
  at.least.1[j] = sum(sample(0:1, size=3, prob=c(0.92,0.08), replace=TRUE))>=1}
sum(at.least.1)/n
```

For this problem it's easy to do it analytically, but sometimes this will be better.

Comment: Thanks for this nice solutiuon. Am I right changing `>=1` to `>=2` and `size`to `4` would mean that I get the chance of having two colorblind people in a group of 4?

Answer (score 1):

The "at least one" probability questions are solved by 1 - prob(none).  So if 0.08 men are color-blind, then 0.92 are not.  So the probability that none of the 3 are color blind is:

```
p3 <- 0.92^3
0.778688
```

And the probability that at least 1 is color blind:

```
at_least_1 <- 1- p3
0.221312
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty easy problem to solve, without using a deep understanding of binomial distributions.

```
prob_male_colorblind=0.08
prob_of_male_not_colorblind=1-prob_male_colorblind
prob_of_three_males_not_colorblind=prob_of_male_not_colorblind^3
prob_of_at_least_one_male_not_colorblind=1-prob_of_three_males_not_colorblind
```